Given $n$ distinct real numbers $p_{i}$ such that $(1+p_{i}\cdot p_{j})^2≤0.99(1+p_{i}^2)(1+p_{j}^2)$ for every $1≤i<j≤n$
The full problem looks like below

Given $n$ distinct real numbers $p_{1}, p_{2}, \ldots, p_{n}$ such that
$$\left(1+p_{i}\cdot p_{j}\right)^2 \leq 0.99 \left(1+p_{i}^2\right)\left(1+p_{j}^2\right)$$
for every $1 \leq i<j \leq n,$
find the maximum value of $n^2+n+8$.

First of all, I realize that the inequality $(1+p_{i}\cdot p_{j})^2 \leq (1+p_{i}^2)(1+p_{j}^2)$ is true based on Cauchy-Schwarz. The equal sign is achieved when $p_{i}=p_{j}$.
Because the problem states that all $p_{i}$ are distinct, then the equal sign can never be achieved, so we have
$$\left(1+p_{i}\cdot p_{j}\right)^2<\left(1+p_{i}^2\right)\left(1+p_{j}^2 \right).$$
The scalar $0.99$ added in the inequality by the problem makes me think that equal sign will be achieved at some $k$ such that $p_{i}=kp_{j}$ with $k<1$. So I plug this into the equation
$$\left(1+p_{i}\cdot p_{j}\right)^2=0.99 \left(1+p_{i}^2\right)\left(1+p_{j}^2\right).$$
But this leads to a more complicated form, and I cannot deduce the value of $k$.

Why does the question ask for $n^2+n+8$, and not simply for $n$?

dunno, the question said so. I tought if i change the problem before i posted it, it may causes a different approach to the problem

The idea is to find a transformation such that the relation
$$ \tag{$*$}
(1+p_{i}\cdot p_{j})^2 \leq 0.99 (1+p_{i}^2)(1+p_{j}^2)
$$
can be simplified using trigonometric identities.
First we note that $(*)$ is symmetric in $i$ and $j$, therefore it holds for all $i, j \in \{ 1, \ldots, n \}$ with $i \ne j$, and we can assume that the $p_i$ are in increasing order.
Here the transformation $x_i = \arctan(p_i) $ does the trick. Then
$$
 -\pi/2 < x_1 \le x_2 \le \cdots \le x_n < \pi/2
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
 \frac{1+p_i p_j}{\sqrt{1+p_i^2} \cdot \sqrt{1+p_j^2}}
&= \frac{1+\tan x_i \tan x_j}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2 x_i} \cdot \sqrt{1+\tan^2 x_j}} \\
&= \cos x_i \cos x_j (1+ \tan x_i \tan x_j) \\
&= \cos x_i \cos x_j + \sin x_i \sin x_j \\
&= \cos(x_j - x_i) 
\end{align}
$$
for $i \ne j$. The relation $(*)$ becomes $\cos(x_j - x_i) \le \sqrt{0.99}$, so that
$$
|x_j - x_i| \ge \arccos(\sqrt{0.99}) 
$$
for $i \ne j$. Then
$$
 \pi > x_n - x_1 = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (x_{k+1}-x_k) \ge (n-1) \arccos(\sqrt{0.99}) 
$$
and therefore
$$
 n \le 1 + \frac{\pi}{\arccos(\sqrt{0.99})} \approx 32.3634
$$
i.e. $ n \le 32$. I leave it to you to show that the bound is sharp.

Remark: This can also be interpreted geometrically as Andreas pointed out in the comments.
Consider the directed line segments from the origin to $(1, p_i)$ in the two-dimensional plane. All line segments are in the right halfplane, and $(*)$ states that
$$
\cos \measuredangle ((1, p_i), (1, p_j)) =
 \frac{\langle (1, p_i), (1, p_j)\rangle}{\Vert (1, p_i) \Vert \cdot \Vert (1, p_j) \Vert} \le \sqrt{0.99} \, ,
$$
i.e. the angle between any two distinct line segments is at least $\arccos(\sqrt{0.99})$.
It follows that $(n-1) \arccos(\sqrt{0.99})  < \pi$, as above.

A little swifter maybe, you could have defined vectors $(1, p_i)$ and then argue that in this two-dimensional space, by  the given inequality and by the $\cos$-definition through scalar products, any two of these vectors must have   an angle at least
$\arccos(\sqrt{0.99})$ between them. That avoids the introduction of the $\tan$, the rest follows with your arguments.

@Andreas: Good idea, I had not seen that. That approach is also closer connected to the  Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, which might be what OP is looking for. You are welcome to write an answer!

@Andreas: But I still wonder why the question asks for the maximum of $n^2+n+8$ instead of $n$.

Yes, $n^2+n+8$ is somewhat strange - maybe OP can tell us why this was asked.

Concerning two-dimensional analysis: I guess I have said it all in the comment, the outline of a full answer would be the same as yours.  Again, the main line is  the $\cos$-definition by scalar products: $\cos^2((1,p_i), (1,p_j)) = \left(1+p_{i}\cdot p_{j}\right)^2/ \left( (1+p_{i}^2)(1+p_{j}^2) \right) \le 0.99$.

@Andreas: I have taken the liberty to add that to the answer, thanks again.

thankyou very much everyone. I really appreciate this. So i got it wrong, there is no use of cauchy in this problem.

About $n^2+n+8$, the question originally is a multiple choice problem. Maybe it is used to make sure we dont use guessing to answer the question.

@AbuNussa In a way, what is used here is $\cos^2((1,p_i), (1,p_j)) = \left(1+p_{i}\cdot p_{j}\right)^2/ \left( (1+p_{i}^2)(1+p_{j}^2) \right) $ and this IS the basis for Cauchy, since Cauchy simply completes it with the general statement $\cos^2((1,p_i), (1,p_j)) \le 1$. So your intuition was in the right direction. Here, the upper limit $1$ however won't help us since we need the values of the $\cos$ explicitely as given in the task.

Thankyou Andreas, that's a very nice explanation
